# Не отображаются данные при реализации парсинга Python

Tags: python, парсер, cmd, beautiful-soup, bs4

заинтересовался идеей парсинга на Python.Суть такова , нужно получить информацию  : Цена , название и ссылка с сайта **https://matraster.ru/matrasy-ceny/**

*Написал вот такой код*

```
import requests

def save():
    with open('parse_info.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(f"{comp['title']} -> Price: {comp['price']} -> Link: {comp['link']}\n")

def parse():
    URL = 'https://matraster.ru/matrasy-ceny/'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Тут он есть'
    } 

    response = requests.get(URL, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'flex product')
    comps = []

    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'title': item.find('div', class_ = 'name').get_text(strip = True),
            'price': item.find('div', class_ = 'price').get_text(strip = True),
            'link': item.find('div', class_ = 'name').get('href')
        })
        global comp
        for comp in comps:
            print(f"{comp['title']} -> Price: {comp['price']} -> Link: {comp['link']}")
            save()
parse()
```

При выполнении через командную строку (от имени администратора) не происходит создания файла , если же убрать функцию сохранения и просто вывести всю информацию через командную строку , то там нет никакой информации.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его [галочкой](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы искали немного не в тех классах, но в целом - хорошая попытка для первого раза!
Переделал немного ваш код с учетом ошибок:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://matraster.ru/matrasy-ceny/'
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
}


def parse():
    response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='item product_item')

    mattress_list = []
    for item in items[3:-1]:
        title_raw = item.find('div', class_='name')

        name = title_raw.find('a').contents[0]
        link = title_raw.find('a')['href']
        current_price = item.find('div', class_='price').find('div').get_text(strip=True)

        mattress_list.append({
            'title': name,
            'price': current_price.replace('р.', '').replace(' ', ''),
            'link': link
        })

    return mattress_list

def save(items):
    with open('parse_info.txt', 'w') as file:
        for item in items:
            file.write(f"{item['title']} -> Price: {item['price']} -> Link: {item['link']}\n")


save(parse())
```

В *parse_info.txt* записывает товары с первой страницы.